# Legend is not aligning correctly

Tags: wpf

I want to use legend like the image below.

[image]

So a square is on the left, the title is on the right.
My code is:

```
<Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Margin="15 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Path Width="12" 
                      Height="12" 
                      Fill="{Binding MarkerFill}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                      <Path.Data>
                        <Binding Path="ActualMarkerGeometry"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:LegendItemControl}">
                        </Binding>
                      </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
```

My question is that the text is not aligning correctly. It align the text to the right rather than the left. See the image below.

[image: test]

**Update code**

```
<telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Path Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding MarkerFill}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">
           <Path.Data>
                        <Binding Path="ActualMarkerGeometry"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:LegendItemControl}">
                        </Binding>
                      </Path.Data>
            </Path>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Margin="15 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" />
             </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:RadLegend.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: show us some code which can reproduce the issue. On seeing the code I can suggest you to create grid with columns and then assign the TextBlock and Path to appropriate columns.

Comment: I did it, assign the TextBlock and Path to the appropriate columns. Same thing.

Comment: post your updated code

Comment: Yeah, see my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the width of the first column to enforce the width same as the square. It seems work. But not sure why?
      `<ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>`